# how they called android graphical server?

Tags: android, linux, android-service

I am wondering what server or service using android for displaying the view. For example in linux it's called Xorg server. Does anyone could tell me how it called in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a Xorg Server on android. They use another approach. Android relies on the standard frame buffer device (/dev/fb0). On top of this, there is an "surface flinger" and then the window manager.

See here for more information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer
- http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/display_drivers.html
- http://people.debian.org.tw/~olv/surfaceflinger/surfaceflinger.pdf
- http://www.slideshare.net/opersys/headless-android